kafka consumer class not found exception
my Spring Boot kafka producer works fine. i tested it using postman. the sent messages are <String,Complaint>, So i used string serializer for the key and Json serializer for the value.
in the other hand, kafka spring boot consumer is also working fine until i publish a message from the producer. it seems that the event is received by the consumer since it triggers it, but i have this error:
2024-07-25T22:40:51.749+01:00 ERROR 26752 --- [kafkaConsumerTest] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.CompletedFetch       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-1, groupId=group_id] Deserializers with error: Deserializers{keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer@44fb7281, valueDeserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer@efa868c}
2024-07-25T22:40:51.749+01:00 ERROR 26752 --- [kafkaConsumerTest] [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Consumer exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler.handleOtherException(DefaultErrorHandler.java:192) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1925) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1348) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition complaints_test-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:331) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.fetchRecords(CompletedFetch.java:283) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.fetchRecords(FetchCollector.java:168) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.FetchCollector.collectFetch(FetchCollector.java:134) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.collectFetch(Fetcher.java:145) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:666) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:617) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.LegacyKafkaConsumer.poll(LegacyKafkaConsumer.java:590) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:874) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1625) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1600) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1405) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1296) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to resolve class name. Class not found [ma.attijari.kafkacomplaintsproducer.models.Complaint]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:137) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.toJavaType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:98) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:571) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:73) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.CompletedFetch.parseRecord(CompletedFetch.java:321) ~[kafka-clients-3.7.1.jar:na]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ma.attijari.kafkacomplaintsproducer.models.Complaint
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:304) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.mapping.DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:133) ~[spring-kafka-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

though i created the same class in the consumer app

and also set the mapping in both producer and consumer to the same name: Complaint
in the consumer (i did the same thing in the producer with the full class name com.example.package.Complaint)
a. in config.java:
config.put(JsonDeserializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "Complaint:com.example.kafkaconsumertest.Complaint");


b. in application.properties:
spring.kafka.consumer.type-mappings=Complaint:com.example.kafkaconsumertest.Complaint

this is my consumer configuration:


i tried to set a mapping for the classes from both sides i tried the Jackson serializer in the producer side:


just found the solution in a medium blog post :
medium blog post
it just sets the option "useHeadersIfPresent" in the JsonDeserializer to false , in the kafka consumer config , like this :
JsonDeserializer<Complaint> jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Complaint.class,false);

